# create a CAD model using programming (preferably python)

Tags: python, automation, cad

I have contour plots of spinal cord sections(C1,C2 .... C36)

I have converted these plots into set of vertices (x,y) for each plot. Now, 
I wish to take these vertices and make a cad model out of it.

For example, if set of vertices (X1,Y1) represent the contour of C1 and (X2, Y2) represent the contour of C2 and the height between C1 and C2 is 1 cm, then I wish to make a 1cm long smooth surface with C1 on the upper surface and C2 vertices on the lower surface and the lateral surface comes by connecting the vertices in C1 and C2. And do this for all the 36 sections of the spinalcord.

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how I can do this, preferably with a sample code?

**P.S :** Even if the suggestion is in a programming language other than python, but please preferably suggest python implementation, as that is what I am more comfortable with and the rest of the project is running on python, so it'll be easy to integrate

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you consider [devDept Eyeshot](http://www.devdept.com) (C#)?

Comment: Fit a curve (either interpolation or approximation) for each section, then use lofting technique to create the surface thru all the "section curves".

Comment: @fang That's the idea even I had in mind... Question is how do I implement it? I wish to deliver a .cad file to someone for further work on this project.

Comment: @Alberto I just checked devDept Eyeshot. It seems that this is only for windows users(I am on Ubuntu) and also, it is a paid software(with 30 days free trial). I wish to use this script multiple times, since my project requires to constantly create and update cad models based on the vertices.

Comment: You can find many literature online for both curve fitting and lofting. To implement them from scratch will take considerable time. So, the best bet is to find a package that already have this done for you. My comment is just to give you a direction about what to search for (and therefore they are posted as comment, instead of answer)

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a python module for such mesh generation: [pymadcad](https://github.com/jimy-byerley/pymadcad) !

If I understand well what you want to do, then perhaps you should directly take a look at the [blending functions](https://pymadcad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/blending.html)
Or eventually at the [extrusion](https://pymadcad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generation.html#madcad.generation.tube) or [tubing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bu6kf.png) functions

this is a typical result of a blended surface between a up and a down line:

```py
from madcad import *

# create two weird outlines, even not plane
# in that case Softened is a particular bspline but that can be your sections instead 
top = wire(Softened([
        vec3(-0.1277,   0.06541,    0),
        vec3(-0.1289,   -0.0629,    0),
        vec3(-0.02201,  -0.1384,    0),
        vec3(0.06227,   -0.03145,   0),
        vec3(0.173, 0.06416,    0),
        vec3(0.1038,    0.1975, 0),
        vec3(-0.01572,  0.1082, 0),
        vec3(-0.08869,  0.1371, 0),
        vec3(-0.1277,   0.06541,    0)]))
down = wire(Softened([
        vec3(-0.06537,  0.05328,    -0.1786),
        vec3(0.04401,   -0.01194,   -0.1431),
        vec3(0.1536,    0.01488,    -0.1826),
        vec3(0.1782,    -0.07515,   -0.1132),
        vec3(0.1412,    -0.1906,    -0.01316),
        vec3(-0.03975, -0.09969, -0.07689),
        vec3(-0.1816,   -0.08512,   -0.04706),
        vec3(-0.1602, 0.01721, -0.1066),
        vec3(-0.06537,  0.05328,    -0.1786)]))
# generate a blended surface
mysurface = blendpair(top, down)

show([mysurface])
```

[image: top and down lines]

gives the following:

[image: blended surface]

I hope it was what you needed